# How to compare the contain of my file with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a log file on my machine called test.log.
I would like to use ansible playbook to search on the content of the log file that the word below exist:

--- text
1230
mode 1

My playbook contain a task with :

- name: Get my log file
  shell: "cat /home/user/test.log"
  register: text1

But how to make sure that my word above exist ?

Comment: If your goal is to look for a string in the log file before going on with other tasks, use the [`wait_for` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html)